# Renaming Databases files in /var/lib/mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, mysql-5.5

I want to do a quick backup of a huge database that takes too long to dump and restore, and create a new temp database to test on. If the test works I will keep the new database, else I will revert to the old one.

Is it alright to rename the database folder at `/var/lib/mysql` to some other name. Then create a new db in MySQL and if I want to switch back to the old database, I will drop the current db and rename the old db folder at `/var/lib/mysql`.

The current software is fixed to use a database of a certain name, hence the reason for renaming the old database.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the full answer to your question, but I have had problems transferring databases from one HDD to another by transferring the "/var/lib/mysql" folders.

If the tables are MyISAM, they will probably work. InnoDB tables may cause problems though.

I have encountered a number of errors when transferring the folders from /var/lib/mysql.
There were no errors with the MyISAM tables.

It does sound like a reasonable idea though.

I wonder if there is any other file outside the /var/lib/mysql which stores some vital information about the databases stored in /var/lib/mysql/.

Let me know if you have found the answer.

What is your method of dumping them? You don't have to download your dumps.
Exporting via PHPMyAdmin takes a long time (from my experience) and is not ideal for very large databases. Instead, create a compressed dump by executing a command via SSH or something and store it on your server, it's quicker that way, although I recommend taking backups placed on other storage devices other than your server, just in case it gets hacked or suffers hardware failure.